# SQLiteDataAdapter converts blank value to 0 - how to prevent that and get blank value?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, adapter

I am using SQLiteDataAdapter, and in my table, there is one row which have blank value('') in it. While reading it from C#, i am getting 0 for the blank value. How to get blank value instead of 0 for blank values?

Column type is Integer, but it may vary based on table to table. And code is :

```
SQLiteDataReader r= command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    DataRow dataRow = new DataRow();
     for (int i = 0; i < l.Count; i++)
     {
          dataRow[listCols[i]] = r[i];
     }
     dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
}
where 'l' is list of DataColumn
```

Comment: What is the type of the column? Could you show the C# code that reads the value?

Comment: and similar question is asked at http://techqa.info/programming/question/29358034/sqlitedataadapter-converts-empty-value-to-0---how-to-prevent-that

Comment: Don't you think integer value can't be null, so it takes ZERO.

Comment: Thats what m asking, my value is not null, instead it is blank, and i want to read blank value but it returns 0 :(

Comment: ok,if you have to write NULL in numeric, then what value will you give? Answer is in question.

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29358034/sqlitedataadapter-converts-empty-value-to-0-how-to-prevent-that, and @geminiousgoel, i am explicitly not converting the value, but it is c# which is directly converts as i event dont know the column datatype (query created dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround to manage null instances on integer columns, check this:
[How to handle nullable integer columns in SQLite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989592/how-to-handle-nullable-integer-columns-in-sqlite-database)

Comment: Thanx Gullie89 for link but in given link, the value is set based on the datatype of the column, in my case, the datatype of column is not known, as query is generated on runtime base on user's operations and user can select any column having any datatype. I just want blank value as it is in my DataRow without knowing the datatype of column. :(